# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 when using groupBy with hasManyThrough relation in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

When using groupBy on hasMany relation it is work fine but
when using groupBy on hasManythrough relation
in my controllr :

```
public function main()
{
    # code...
    $user = Auth::user();
    $results = [
                'vacations' => $user->vacations()->groupBy('type')->selectRaw('sum(days) as days,sum(mins) as mins, type')->get(), //works fine
                'vactionRegisterd' => $user->vacationsRegisterd()->groupBy('type')->selectRaw('sum(days) as days,sum(mins) as mins, type')->get(), //works fine
                'empVacations'=>$user->empVacations, //work fine
                'employees_vacations'=>$user->empVacations()->groupBy('type')->selectRaw('sum(days) as days,sum(mins) as mins, type')->get(),//gives an error 
               ];
    return view('dashboard.dashboard', ['results' => $results]);
}
```

I have this error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'hrweb.users.manager_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select sum(days) as
> days,sum(mins) as mins, type, `users`.`manager_id` as
> `laravel_through_key` from `vacations` inner join `users` on
> `users`.`id` = `vacations`.`user_num` where `users`.`manager_id` = 5
> group by `type`)I have tow tables `users` ,`vacations`

I don't know why (**users.manager_id as laravel through key**) is used even though I didn't use "**users.manager_id**" with "**groupBy**" or "**selectRow**" method.

My Code in user model :

1- user has many employees where employees are also users with different role and with `manager_id != null` [`user->employees`]

```
/**
 * Get all of the employees from user table for the current admin User
 */
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'manager_id');
}
```

2- user has many vacations [`user->vacations`]

```
/**
 * Get all of the vacations for the User
 */
public function vacations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vacations', 'user_num', 'id');
}
```

3- user hasManyThrough vacations [`user->employees->vacation`]

```
 /**
 * Get all of the employees vacations for the User
 */
public function empVacations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Vacations::class, User::class, 'manager_id', 'user_num', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: This is due to MySQL default `sql_mode` setting which is [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the Error again ,I noted that Laravel use the foreign key as `laravel_through_key` in the query in some way.

The problem solved by adding `laravel_through_key` in the groupBy() method like this :

```
[...
 'employees_vacations'=>$user->empVacations()
       -> groupBy('laravel_through_key','user_num','type')
       -> selectRaw('sum(days) as days,sum(mins) as mins,user_num, type')->get()
 ]
```

But I still think there is a better solution so I will be happy to know your answers ^_^